# D3js scale conversion for generating path in line graph was not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, linechart

Trying to Generate multiple line graphs using d3js library,
I had a data set and using a linear scale for both the x and y-axis.

the line graph generated was crossing boundaries of SVG and one some portion of lines are displayed.
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1nLm.png)
[Actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zqkO.png)
[image: How it was behaving]

```
data = [
{
values:[
{x:2,y:3},
{x:4,y:5}
]
}
,
{
values:[
{x:2,y:3},
{x:4,y:5}
]
}
];
let xScale = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([min, max])
            .range([0, width]);
let yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([min, max])
        .rangeRound([this.height, 0]);

 this.svg = d3
      .select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', gWidth + 'px')
      .attr('height', gHeight + 'px') // for lables
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);

    let line = d3
      .line()
      .x((d: any) => this.xScale(d.x))
      .y((d: any) => this.yScale(d.y));
    let lines = this.svg.append('g').attr('class', 'lines');

    lines
      .selectAll('.line-group')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'line-group')
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
      .style('stroke', (d, i) => this.color(i))
      .style('opacity', 1);
```

Comment: The images don't correspond to your data - nor to the code you've shared. In the code block the min of each scale's domain is the same: `min`, and it's unclear what value that is. In the images, each scale has a different minimum domain value and it's unclear how you've set those. Without more info only guesses are possible: if the code shown is what you have, it could just be that you are not accounting for the margin you are using to translate the `g` that holds the plot: your y scale range shouldn't be `[height,0]` if the plot is only supposed be `gHeight` pixels tall.

Comment: @AndrewReid the data which I have provided is the sample data,
I had implemented that graph with the reference of this one (https://codepen.io/zakariachowdhury/pen/JEmjwq), But I am using scale linear for both axis.

Comment: @AndrewReid I suspect that my line function was not converting the data which would fit the size of my SVG. Min and Max are the values that are calculated based on the entire data set. I was attaching another picture I can find the full path by changing the size of the SVG.

Comment: If your line function isn't converting the data to fit the size of the SVG it is likely because you haven't defined your scales correctly. Your shared code shows the same `[min,max]` domain for both x and y, but your images show an x domain of `[0,200]` and a y domain of ~ `[-.3,1.9]`, this doesn't match your shared code. It's not clear how you are calculating min and max, but you problem likely lies there, or, it lies in using a range that is the full width/height of the SVG despite having margins, but I'm not sure how you define the margins/width/height either. This complicates answering.

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the issue at hand, or at least seeing how you define everything relevant, it is not possible to provide an answer with any certainty that it addresses the actual issue you are facing.

Comment: @AndrewReid, by following your observation I found the issue, it was due to min and max value calculation, thanks for responding previously the maximum domain value of both x and y-axis are the same so the graph was crossing the axis.